# Pip install from requirements.txt _after_ other installation

Tags: python, pip

I have a few dependencies that are installed from github, and one of them (A) depends on the existence of some others (in particular, Cython).  Putting all of the dependencies in requirements.txt results in a nonexistence error; A does not see Cython installed in order to start setup.  Is there a way to specify that a dependency is installed *after* other dependencies have been fully installed?

Comment: Why don't you just have multiple requirement files, and install them in order?

Comment: Doesn't a package install all the dependencies it requires first? Why would it error out?

Comment: @MartinKonecny:  I do not maintain these packages, only use them.  I do not know why there are dependencies specified in the readme but not enforced on installation.

Comment: Try posting the error message. Perhaps it is trying to install dependency but that is failing.